# Monitor command input on python VTE terminal widget

Tags: python, terminal, gtk, vte

I am looking to monitor every command input on python VTE widget so I can pass it to the my program for processing on commands that match a certain regex. Is it possible, I am thing connecting signals and all that but I just don't know anything further than than. Any help please?

Thanks,

Comment: I think you need to connect the "commit" signal. Additional link:
https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Vte-2.91/classes/Terminal.html#Vte.Terminal.signals.commit